# Grabbing a specific revision number that contains a specific substring

Tags: file, batch-file, mercurial, tags, revision

I am new to writing batch files and have done a lot of research to no avail.

-What I currently have:
I am currently using a Mercurial Repository. In my current batch file, I need to specify two different revisions as parameters in order for it to work. First parameter is the starting revision number while the second is the current revision number.

-What I am trying to do:
I was wondering if there was some way to loop through the revision numbers of your current branch and grab the number that contains a certain substring in its tag. Say you have Revision 1840 with tag MyProd_1840 and Revision 1800 with tag MyDev_1800.

-Question:
If I am in the latest revision number (say 1855), how do I loop through previous numbers and grab the revision number containing "Dev" in its string; thus, returning 1800?"

-What I have found:
The only thing I know so far is that "hg id -n" returns the revision number of the revision you are currently on (that I am assuming I can use for the second parameter).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `hg help revsets` ???

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was able to find that "hg id -n -r [tag]" (without brackets) returns the revision number given a specific tag. That much closer to getting to what I want the batch file to do.

Comment: Maybe you'll describe your **full business-task**? Because with revsets (and templating in output) you can perform a lot of tricks easy

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My program is currently going to contain something like this

```
 @echo off
 SET COMMAND=hg id -n
 SET COMMAND2=hg id -n -r "keyword(champion_prod)"
 @echo %COMMAND%

 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('%COMMAND%') DO @set endRev=%%A

 echo %endRev%
 echo %endRev%
 echo %endRev%

 @echo %COMMAND2%

 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('%COMMAND2%') DO @set startRev=%%A

 echo %startRev%
 echo %startRev%
 echo %startRev%

 endlocal 
 exit /b 0
```

in case anyone else is running into the same problem. the " is needed in COMMAND2 for keyword(champion_prod) because, when you call COMMAND2 in the For, the cmd prompt will think you're trying to call a command within a command and give you a ") was unexpected at this time" error. "hg id -n -r keyword(string)" will return the latest revision number that contains the given string (I believe it searches both the description as well as the tag for said string. I may be wrong on the tag). But this works for me.